# Hosting domain on local server

Tags: dns, glassfish, hosting

I don't know if its cool to ask  this question or not. Please forgive me if I am wrong.

I even don't know concept what I am trying to implement is possible or not.

Anyway here is my ques:

I have purchased a domain and I want to host it on my personal computer on which GlassFish in running and my computers's connection  will be up and running fine.

When I try to update nameservers in my domain to my computer's IP it ask for two fields, hostname and IP address. I, of course, know my IP address but what is my hostname? I tried my pc's name but it says invalid.

Is it something to do with Glassfish?
Am I doing something really wrong?

Please help me if possible, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you acquired DNS service for the domain name in question? Without name servers delegated to the domain name, it will not go where you need it to go.

For this, I would recommend Dyn Standard DNS (http://dyn.com/dns/dyn-standard-dns/). Once you have purchased DNS for this domain, you will enter your machine's IP as the A-record, and use the assigned name servers as such.